# Function call in script and command line gets different result

Tags: matlab, function, structure

I have a matlab-function `tutorial_main(xalpha)` that returns me a `struc` element with 2 entries (due to copyright, I can't provide you with the function :( )

Whenever I call the function from the command line with

`fit_t = [];
alpha = 0.01;
fit_t =  [fit_t tutorial_main(alpha)];`

it works just fine.

Whenever I do the same in a script inside a loop, I get an error:

```
fit_t = []
for alpha = 0.01:0.01:1
  tic;
  fit_t =  [fit_t tutorial_main(alpha)];
  time = toc;
end
```

The error is:

```
Improper assignment with rectangular empty matrix.

Error in tutorial_main (line 286)
    ML(1) = myvect(p{1}(max(marglik{1})==marglik{1}));

Error in ass5 (line 14)
    fit_t =  [fit_t tutorial_main(alpha)];
```

and sometimes it runs for a few iterations but after the third gives me

```
In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the 

Error in tutorial_main (line 286)
    ML(1) = myvect(p{1}(max(marglik{1})==marglik{1}));

Error in ass5 (line 14)
    fit_t =  [fit_t tutorial_main(alpha)];same.
```

I really don't understand why I get this error message. The function should in both cases be called the same way. Running `clear all` before does not change anything.

Now the weirdest part:
When I set a *breakpoint* at `time = toc`, and continue manually after every loop, I do NOT get an error. Removing the `tic/toc` does not help.
Edit: Okay, sometimes I also get an error with breakpoints.

Comment: Without example code that replicates your issue I'm not sure what you're expecting anyone to be able to do. Use [`dbstop if error`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html#buzezti-1) to evaluate your workspace when the error is thrown. I would also consider that [`max`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) does not necessarily return a single value.

Comment: well, as I am calling the function essentially with the same commands, I thought there should be something generally wrong? Shouldn't the function return the same when called with the same values?

Comment: It's not running with the same values. Your `alpha` is changing in the loop.

Comment: You can always try solving the problem with the command dbstop if error and test what's wrong with the matrix you are assigning to.

It will start a debug just before the line when you get the error. In that way, you will figure out what those particular values of alpha are doing to the function and hopefully you will figure out the problem.

You can't get more than this I think from SO, since there is no code that can be tested. Maybe a more descriptive info might help a bit, but I doubt that without a code someone will give you a full answer of your problem.

Comment: Improper assignment with rectangular empty matrix occurs for code of the form x(I)=r, where r is m-by-n, and one and only one of m or n is zero (e.g. r could be 1-by-0).

Answer (score 2):

Are you positive that your function returns a scalar or at least a row vector?

The difference is that `fit_t = [fit_t retval];` is always OK if initially `fit_t=[]`, but if it already has a scalar/row vector value then you run into problems unless `retval` (the return value) is a scalar/row vector.

Your error saying `In an assignment  A(I) = B, the...` also suggests this: your right-hand side is probably a vector in `ML(1) = myvect()...`, most likely `marglik{1}` doesn't have a unique maximum, so `max(marglik{1})==marglik{1}` returns a logical vector with multiple non-zeros, so `p{1}(max...)` is a vector, which collides with `ML(1)` on the left side. You need to choose one value from the ones in `max(marglik{1})==marglik{1}` in case there are several ones.

(This, or the magic fairies used the wrong kind of binary dust on your secret function. Really hard to debug a black box if we don't even know what it outputs.)

Comment: Yes, but my problem is, that the function ALWAYS runs fine when started from the command line and almost always fails when run within a script, even though the call is with the same values. How is this possible?

Comment: @skjerns Have you tried manually reproducing the loop? As in `fit_t=[]; alpha = 0.01;
fit_t =  [fit_t tutorial_main(alpha)]; alpha=0.02;  fit_t =  [fit_t tutorial_main(alpha)];` etc. all the way to `alpha=1`? Along the way you should run into your errors.

Comment: indeed, if I run the code manually in the console, it works without error. As soon as I do it with a for-loop it stops working.

Comment: @skjerns But do you actually proceed with all the iterations of the for loop manually? I'm only asking because in your question you seem to imply that you only try it once, which makes all the difference.

Comment: Nnd now after restarting matlab the code suddenly works. I don't get it. And yes, I've tried 10 values of the iteration before manually and no problem. As said in the question: When using breakpoints, the code runs! Without breakpoints it didn't. Mysterious.

Comment: @skjerns there are all sorts of mysteries in the world.